# Positional Argument Error: Classes and Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I am testing out bits of code for a Tkinter program and want to have a main menu and then the game itself.

I want to put the main menu in the `__init__()` function and then when a button is pressed, it calls the command to delete the main menu and load new widgets. For testing i have only included 2 buttons as my widgets just to play around with the idea. But it comes up with an error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        But = ttk.Button(master, text = "Play", command = self.Play).pack()

    def Play(self, master):
        self.But.destroy()
        ttk.Button(master, text = "Test Button").pack()



def main():            

    root = Tk()
    Menu = Application(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

When clicking the "Play" Button, this error happens:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

I am quite new to using classes for tkinter programming. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because when you defined the `Play()` function (in `def Play(self, master)`) you have specified a positional parameter called `master` which is mandatory but then you ignored it when you used this same function as a callback for your `ttk.Button` widget. This means you should code it this way: `lambda:self.Play(master)`.

Once you do that, the Python interpreter will inform you that you have done other mistakes elsewhere in your program. So let me give you a final solution to your program following [***PEP8***](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.master, text = "play", command = self.play)
        self.button.pack()

    def play(self):
        self.button.destroy()
        self.new_button = ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Test Button")
        self.new_button.pack()


def main():  
    root = tk.Tk()
    Menu = Application(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
   main()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me :). Will compare my code to your edit so i can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do not understand why I did this or that thing, please let me know. @Tweakforce_LG

Comment: I dont understand why i get this error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'.

Unless i use pack() on self.Button rather than the actual button before making it a variable

Comment: if you mean the error shown in your question, it occurs because you defined `Play()` function with a parameter you named `master`. This means each time you call `Play()` you must specify an argument to it like this `Play(your_argument)`. This is a common concept to all programming languages you use. But you forgot to do that when you did `command=self.Play` because, as you can see, you did not inject any argument to it. You should have done it this way: `comand=self.Play(master)` to respect the definition you gave to `Play()`. This is the reason of that error @Tweakforce_LG

Comment: Sorry, i ment the error - 
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'.". - 
This happens if i pack the button by putting .pack() at the end of the button, rather than packing the button underneath once its been defined as self.button. Thanks for the help @Billal BEGUERADJ

Comment: That error occurs because when you do something like this: `variable = tkinter.SomeWidgetType(parameters).pack()` then you must know `variable` here has `None` value because `pack()` always returns `None` (Because in Python,  functions without a specified return value always return `None`). Then later in `Play()` you tried to run `destroy()` on a `None` value, it means on something empty, or does not exist. So Python triggers that error because he does not know how to destroy something that does not exist @Tweakforce_LG

Comment: I understand it all now, thanks, you've been a big help.

Comment: `command=self.Play(Master)` which you suggest in the opening paragraph is unquestionably wrong. That will _immediately_ call `Play` and assign `None` to the `command` attribute.